# Implementation of the undef function

Tags: c, beginner, linked-list, hash-map

> Write a function `undef` that will remove a name and a definition from the maintained by `lookup` and `install`.

Here is my solution:

```
void undef(char *name)
{
    struct Nlist *tmp  = hashtab[hash(name)];

    if(!strcmp(tmp->name, name)) { // delete the head node
        hashtab[hash(name)] = tmp->next;
        free(tmp->name);
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }

    for(; strcmp(tmp->next->name, name); tmp = tmp->next)
        ;

    struct Nlist *save = tmp->next; // save the desired node for deletion
    tmp->next          = tmp->next->next; // adjust the links
    free(save->name);
    free(save);
}
```

There are 2 main cases. The first is when we want to delete the head node, and when we want to delete a node from the rest of the list.

I will explain how my function works in the second case. The `for` loop will run until `tmp` will point to the node that precedes the desired node. Then I adjust the links and free the memory occupied by the desired node.

This approach is not good if the desired value is located at the head node, so I use a `if`-statement to check if the desired value is located at the head node. If it is, I adjust the head pointer and free the memory.

Here is the code for the entire program: http://ideone.com/t0bjiA.

Comment: Who wrote the rest of the program especially the `lookup` and `install` functions?

Comment: They are extracted from k&r2, but they were adapted by me. As you can see, they look a little bit weird because I've tried to adapt them to work with a previous version of undef. I forgot to remove those changes.

Comment: Consider posting the entire program here.  Links tend to go away after a while and that would render this question rather useless without the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to special-case the head of the list if you think about it in a different way.  In particular, each entry in your `hashtable` is a pointer to an `Nlist` structure, so if you take the *address* of the `hashtable` entry, you can treat it just like any other node.  Specifically, you can use this:

```
void undef(char *name)
{
    struct Nlist **tmp = &hashtab[hash(name)];
    struct Nlist *old;

    /* find our matching node */
    for ( ; *tmp && strcmp(name, (*tmp)->name); tmp=&((*tmp)->next));

    /* if we have found it, delete and adjust pointer */
    if (*tmp != NULL) {
        old = *tmp;
        free(old->name);
        free(old->defn);
        *tmp = old->next;
        free(old);
    }
}
```

Also note that `defn` was not being deleted in your original code, resulting in a memory leak.